# 'remove subview' will remove the related constraint.How does iOS worked?

Tags: ios, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

Assume that there has two subviews in a containView.

[image]

Don't consider the width and height constraint,just think they are equal to a constant.

#### Subview1:

has a leading and top constraint to superview.And a 'horizontol constraint' to subview2.

#### Subview2:

has a trailing and top constaint to superview.

---

As I known, if i hide the subview2,the 'horizontol constraint' still exist.But if i remove it from containView.What does the project do to remove the 'horizontal constaint'?

I think the subview2 is like a root-node of muti-tree.If it was removedFromSuperview,the root-node retain count is 0,then child node's(like constraint) retaincount released...
Another idea is when remove subviews,uiview will traverse it's constraint array and remove some constraint related to nil view.

Am i right?Can someone give me opinion?

---

I've tried this,

[image]

And here is the log behind remove and removed:

```html
<__NSArrayI 0x1740ec480>(
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x17008a690 _UILayoutGuide:0x100211410.height == 20   (active)>,
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x170089d80 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x100211410]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x100210b30 )>,
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x17008a780 _UILayoutGuide:0x1002119c0.height == 0   (active)>,
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x17008a730 _UILayoutGuide:0x1002119c0.bottom == UIView:0x100210b30.bottom   (active)>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17008a500 UIView:0x100211270.leading == UIView:0x100210b30.leadingMargin + 6   (active)>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17008a550 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x100211410]-(210)-[UIView:0x100211270]   (active)>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17008a5a0 H:[UIView:0x100211270]-(99)-[UIView:0x100210ed0]   (active)>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17008a5f0 UIView:0x100210ed0.centerY == UIView:0x100211270.centerY   (active)>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17008a640 UIView:0x100210b30.trailingMargin == UIView:0x100210ed0.trailing + 11   (active)>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1740853c0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x100210b30.height == 667   (active)>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x174085460 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Left' UIView:0x100210b30.minX == 0   (active, names: '|':UIWindow:0x100405340 )>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x174085410 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' UIView:0x100210b30.minY == 0   (active, names: '|':UIWindow:0x100405340 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1740852d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x100210b30.width == 375   (active)>
)


(lldb) po self.view.constraints
<__NSArrayI 0x1700a7680>(
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x17008a690 _UILayoutGuide:0x100211410.height == 20   (active)>,
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x170089d80 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x100211410]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x100210b30 )>,
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x17008a780 _UILayoutGuide:0x1002119c0.height == 0   (active)>,
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x17008a730 _UILayoutGuide:0x1002119c0.bottom == UIView:0x100210b30.bottom   (active)>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17008a500 UIView:0x100211270.leading == UIView:0x100210b30.leadingMargin + 6   (active)>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17008a550 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x100211410]-(210)-[UIView:0x100211270]   (active)>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1740853c0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x100210b30.height == 667   (active)>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x174085460 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Left' UIView:0x100210b30.minX == 0   (active, names: '|':UIWindow:0x100405340 )>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x174085410 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' UIView:0x100210b30.minY == 0   (active, names: '|':UIWindow:0x100405340 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1740852d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x100210b30.width == 375   (active)>
)
```

This line was removed after subview2 removed:

> NSLayoutConstraint:0x17008a5a0 H:[UIView:0x100211270]-(99)-[UIView:0x100210ed0]   (active)

Comment: Are you asking what to do about constraints if you remove `subview2`? I really don't know what retain counts have to do with this.

Comment: @NRitH No.I just want to know the principle that how did the horizontal constraint dismiss...I don't know my idea is right or wrong

Comment: Are you doing it programmatically?

Comment: @SMi Yes,see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `UIView` has an array (`constraints`)of `[NSLayoutConstraint]`s that:

1. Constrain the view's size (e.g. `.Height`);
2. Constrain the view to one of its subviews; or
3. Constrain two of its `subviews` to each other.

When a view is deleted, all of the constraints in its `constraints` are deleted or deactivated. Then its superview's, and its superview's superview's, constraints are examined, and any that involve the view to be deleted are deleted or deactivated.